# Resize a directory in CentOS..the simplest request, right?

Tags: resize, directory, centos

How to do it?
I want to add storage to the following directory

```
    /var/lib/libvirt/images
```

How do I do it?

I went to CentOS forum and it's not there..the simplest task of resizing a directory.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Resizing directories? Either I am totally missing something about CentOS or that's just not possible, directories don't have sizes

Comment: Indeed. Is that a mounted partition? If so what kind of filesystem? What partition? Is there extra disk space available somewhere? Is lvm involved?

Comment: @EtanReisner ext4 filesystem, it's part of root partition. I have more than enough on /home which I can allocate but I don't know how to.

Comment: You can't move space between partitions that easily (or often at all) if they aren't using lvm or something similar.